# Handled RoutedEvent continues to bubble up tree

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, treeviewitem, routedevent

I'm developing a `TreeView` based control and my double click event continues to bubble up my `TreeViewItem` nodes.

The goal is to have the `TreeViewItem` expand or collapse when it is double clicked.

I have a style that applies an event handler for the `MouseDoubleClick` event to each `TreeViewItem`.

Here's the code that handles the event

```
private void TreeViewItemDoubleClicked( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    // Get the specific tree view item that was double clicked
    TreeViewItem treeViewItem = sender as TreeViewItem;

    // not null?
    if( null != treeViewItem )
    {
         // Switch expanded state
         if( true == treeViewItem.IsExpanded )
         {
             treeViewItem.IsExpanded = false;
         }
         else
         {
             treeViewItem.IsExpanded = true;
         }

         // Set event handled
         e.Handled = true; // [1]
    }
}
```

This works fine for the top level `TreeViewItem` however when a child is double clicked, the event bubbles up the tree causing the entire branch to collapse. Why is the event continuing to bubble? As noted a `[1]` I'm setting the event as handled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hate answering my own questions but here is the solution that I ultimately came to use.

After coming across a few sources that specified that the MouseDoubleClick is raised for each TreeViewItem in the branch ( from child up to the root ) regardless if the event is handled I utilized the answer from this question:

[WPF TreeView, get TreeViewItem in PreviewMouseDown event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941762/wpf-treeview-get-treeviewitem-in-previewmousedown-event)

to get the TreeViewItem that was under the mouse event. If the current sender is equal to the TreeViewItem of the mouse event I expand/collapse as required. Otherwise, I just ignore the event and do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

No idea why, but the selected answer didn't work for every `TreeViewItems` for me. So I used a simple `bool` approach to fence from reeintering `TreeViewItemDoubleClicked` more than once.

```
private void TreeViewItemDoubleClicked( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    // Make sure the event has never been handled first
    if (bubblingBulkwark)
        return;

    // Get the specific tree view item that was double clicked
    TreeViewItem treeViewItem = sender as TreeViewItem;

    // not null?
    if( null != treeViewItem )
    {
         // Switch expanded state
         if( true == treeViewItem.IsExpanded )
         {
             treeViewItem.IsExpanded = false;
         }
         else
         {
             treeViewItem.IsExpanded = true;
         }

         // Raise bulkwark
         bubblingBulkwark = true;
    }
}
```

To allow the very first handler invoked to execute fully (therefore relying on the fact that a child's handler will be called before it's parent's), simply add :

```
private void TreeView_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    bubblingBulkwark = false;
}
```

And don't forget to register it.

```
treeView.PreviewMouseDown += TreeView_PreviewMouseDown;
```